# How to listen click event using css selector in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular6, angular2-directives

```
     <ul>
        <li class="apply"></li>
        <li class="apply"></li>
        <li class="apply"></li>
        <li class="apply"></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <a class="apply" href="#"></a>
        <a class="apply" href="#"></a>
        <a class="apply" href="#"></a>
        <a class="apply" href="#"></a>
    </div>
```

How to listen click event on all elements whose has a `class="apply"` attached to it in angular 2+. In jQuery all these elements can be accessed using `$(".apply").onClick()`

Note. This code is generated manually without using *ngFor directive. A project in jQuery needs to be converted into angular 6 where `class="apply"` is being used more than hundred of times in different ways, thats why it is not hard to use *ngFor for each case.

Comment: Stop thinking jQuery way. You are now on Angular. The answer below shouldn't be a correct answer. It's not good practice to do the following in the long run it will be a headache to maintain the app

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this without the use of jQuery is to just use basic JavaScript, which is what jQuery is just doing in the background anyway.

You could do the following to attach an event listener to all elements with the class `apply`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.attach();
}

attach(): void {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('apply')).forEach((element: HTMLElement) => {
        element.addEventListener('click', this.eventHandler);
    });
}

detach(): void {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('apply')).forEach((element: HTMLElement) => {
        element.removeEventListener('click', this.eventHandler);
    });
}

private eventHandler = (ev: MouseEvent) => {
    console.log(ev.target);
}
```